# How can I manage the error: TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, zigbee

I would like to make too zigbee devices speak together using RaspberryPi. 
I'm using the Xbee "extension", and serie 1 end-devices.
They currently transmitting datas and I would like to extract a specific data for the librarie. My code is simple.

```
#coding: utf
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
# for serie 1 componants
from xbee import XBee 
# for serie 2 componants
#from xbee import ZigBee 


##############################################################
def CalcDCAmps(data):
    mes = (data*20)/1024    # conversion 0-1023 en 0-20mA

    if (mes <4) :   #si la valeur reçues est inférieure à 4mA
        return -1 # problème sur le capteur
    else :
        return (mes*50)/20  # conversion 4-20mA en 0-50A

##############################################################


# Open serial port
serial_port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600)

# Create XBee Series 1 object
zb = XBee(serial_port)
#zb = ZigBee(serial_port)



while True:
    j = 0;
    data_int = "";

    try:
        data = zb.wait_read_frame() #Get data for later use
        #print data # for debugging only
        print data['samples']# print the data frame of the list
        # frame type received[{'adc-0': 1023}]

        sample = str(data['samples']) #transformation de l'élément de la bibliothèque en chaîne de caractères
    #print "Equivalent String : %s" % sample

        for i in range(len(sample)):    # boucle pour isoler les chiffres de la chaîne de caractères
            if ((sample[i]>='0') & (sample[i]<='9')) :
                data_int += sample[i]   # stockage des chiffres dans une nouvelle chaîne de caractères

        data_int = int(data_int) # conversion de la chaîne de caractère en entier
        print "Valeur extraite:", data_int  

        courant = CalcDCAmps(data_int)
        print "Courant DC: ", courant, "A"

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

    serial_port.close()
```

(sorry for french comments)
When I compute it this appear:

```
[{'adc-0': 172}]
Valeur extraite: 172
Courant DC:  -1 A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conversion_v3.py", line 36, in <module>
    data = zb.wait_read_frame() #Get data for later use
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xbee/base.py", line 399, in wait_read_frame
    frame = self._wait_for_frame()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xbee/base.py", line 117, in _wait_for_frame
    if self.serial.inWaiting() == 0:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 431, in inWaiting
    s = fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCINQ, TIOCM_zero_str)
TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method.
```

And now I don't know how to manage it. Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing the serial port inside your loop, so it can't read a frame anymore after the first iteration.